# QB64 Output issue

Tags: basic

How do I scroll up and see previous displayed lines in the output?

I'm using QB64, and had to run a program 1000 times, but I cannot see the starting lines. Actually, I can't see the first 800 lines or so.

Is there a way to expand the window or scroll up to see everything? Because I do not have a scroll bar, and if I use any key to scroll up, it exits the console window.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could count the lines and pause every 25th line or so.

Answer (score 2):

The new version of QB64 supports a console window, which should be able to do what you want. I'm not too used to console though, but if all else fails you could always save the text in a string array and examine that. There are some examples of creating lists in the community at qb64.net or you could make your own list with scrollbars, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Input a line in the loop for data output:

```
if x > 24 then
   if 24 MOD x then sleep
endif
```

`MOD` is the command for modulus where the modulus will return the remainder of `24` and `x`.  in this case if it is zero then it will pause the console output until the user presses any key.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with custom buffers, just use the console:

```
$CONSOLE:ONLY
_DEST _CONSOLE
```

With that in the begining of your program, QB64 will create only a console window, which by default can be scrolled back so the past lines can be seen.

Comment: I used your suggestion and it's good. But, when I run the SW in the IDE, the IDE hangs. Have you a solution? (I use Linux).

Comment: You probably have an older version of QB64. Either way, use CTRL+F5 to run detached from the IDE.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem remains, in my LUBUNTU the program is launched, but runs in a window that remains invisible and inaccessible.